# Converting negative values into positive dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

Am having a `VARCHAR` column in my database which contains negative values and while retrieving I need to convert it into positive. The problem is I know if its integer I can use `abs()` function but since column is `VARCHAR` I can not use `abs()` function. Can you please help me?

This is my query:

```
select distinct column_name  from table_name order by column_name
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output, because we don't know how it stored the negative values in your case in varchar data type.

Comment: Why on earth do you store numbers as `VARCHAR`? Change the data type of this column.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you only want positive and negative integers as valid strings,
you could use :

```
select CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(s,'^-?[0-9]+$') 
       THEN abs(s) END 
  FROM t;
```

This will return `null` for non-integers.

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be913/1)

In Oracle 12c R2 and above, this can be achieved by `TO_NUMBER`'s `DEFAULT` clause

```
select ABS( TO_NUMBER( s DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) ) FROM t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert to number first, using [to_number](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) function:

```
select distinct abs(to_number(column_name)) from table_name order by column_name
```

> Oracle SQL TO_NUMBER function converts a string to a number

**EDIT**

This is assuming all the values can be converted to numbers, if not add a condition to remove irrelevant values

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `to_number()` will only work without issues provided **all the values** in `column_name` can be converted to numbers. This is always a potential problem when numbers are stored as strings.

Comment: Thanks  a lot it helped

Comment: With string to number conversions prior to Oracle 12.2, _"a condition to remove irrelevant values"_ is the whole challenge.